# Парсинг конкретных переменных из одного JSON файла в другой

Tags: python, json

Пытаюсь достать из JSON файла нужную мне информацию (строчку Name) и поместить её в другой JSON файл.
Вот моя попытка сделать это,но ругается на data = json.load(file),что только не перепробовал,все время именно на эту строчку.
Особо не ругайте,только начинаю пытаться разобраться в этом.

```
import json

with open ("test1.json","r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    with open("res.json", "w") as outfile:
    data = json.load(file)
        for i in data['Name']: 
            outfile.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Вот мой JSON

```
{
  "Name": Oleg,
  "Age": "25",
  "Date": "22.11.1983"
}{
  "Name": Nikolai,
  "Age": "21",
  "Date": "05.02.1994"
}{
  "Name": Egor,
  "Age": "19",
  "Date": "19.02.1990"
}
```

Comment: На что ругается то? Я вижу потенциальную ошибку табуляции и то, что сам JSON файл некорректен (нет запятых между '}{' и все это не заключено в '{}').

Comment: Во-первых, как уже сказали, невалидный JSON (нет запятых между словарями и нет `[` в начале и `]` в конце файла). Во-вторых, Вы на каждой итерации в новый файл дампаете полностью содержимое первого файла, а не только что-то конкретное. В-третьих, модуль `json` умеет дампать сразу в файл, незачем делать лишний вызов дампа в строку, а затем эту строку писать в файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного более сложный пример c 2-мя вариантами вывода отфильтрованных данных:

```
import json

with open ("test.json","r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    out_data = []
    for i in range(0,3):
       data2=data['members']
       data3=data2[i]
       out_data.append(data3['Name'])
    with open("res1.json", "w") as file_out1:
       file_out1.write(json.dumps(out_data))
    with open("res2.json", "w") as file_out2:
       json.dump(out_data, file_out2, sort_keys=False, indent=2)
```

Содержимое файла test.json:

```
{
 "members": [
   {
     "Name": "Oleg",
     "Age": "25",
     "Date": "22.11.1983"
    },
    {
     "Name": "Nikolai",
     "Age": "21",
     "Date": "05.02.1994"
    },
    {
     "Name": "Egor",
     "Age": "19",
     "Date": "19.02.1990"
    }
  ]
}
```

На выходе получаем два файла:

res1.json содержит строку:

```
["Oleg", "Nikolai", "Egor"]
```

res2.json содержит принятый читаемый код:

```
[
  "Oleg",
  "Nikolai",
  "Egor"
]
```

Как видите, не все так просто в работе на Python с форматами json.

P.S. Если для res2.json установить "sort_keys=True", то получим отсортированный по ключу json-файл. Но в данном примере keys в выходных файлах отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Вот валидный json-файл с первоначальными данными:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Oleg",
        "Age": "25",
        "Date": "22.11.1983"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Nikolai",
        "Age": "21",
        "Date": "05.02.1994"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Egor",
        "Age": "19",
        "Date": "19.02.1990"
    }
]
```

Вот сам код по обработке данных:

```py
import json

# считываем данные из json-файла с первоначальными данными
with open(r'/path/to/src.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as srcfl:
    data = json.load(srcfl)

# собираем нужные нам данные из записей
out_data = [ i["Name"] for i in data ]

# сохраняем данные в новый json-файл 
with open(r'/path/to/out.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfl:
    json.dump(out_data, outfl, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

В результате получим вот такой JSON-файл:

```
[
    "Oleg",
    "Nikolai",
    "Egor"
]
```